# Reduce boot disk size of a GKE cluster

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

Is it possible to change boot disk size of a GKE cluster? I created clusters with 50GB boot disk but I don't need this much. I can't find any option to reduce the boot disk size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't change the boot disk of existing node pool. You can

- Either create a new Node Pool with a smaller boot disk image size
- Or delete your cluster and create a new one

*Note: The pulled image are stored locally on each node, on the boot disk free space. If you have a lot of large images pulled on the same node, you can have issues with available space.*

Comment: Thanks. Am I correct that boot disk space same as HDD size. So 50GB boot space mean 50GB HDD? My web application doesn't store any data on the disk. So if the web application doesn't need say more than 1 GB space, I can safely go for say 5GB boot disk space (or is 5GB too less)?

Comment: I think the smallest size is 10Gb. This size include the OS, kubelet and other K8S stuffs, such as the container images pulled by the node when a POD is deployed on it. If your pod need to claim a volume to store persistent data, it's another persistent disk which is attached to the node and not the boot disk space which is used.

Answer (score 1):

Currently it is possible to change the image type of an existing cluster but not the disk size yet as I guess it would generate quite complex issues if you set a too small boot disk.

The way I achieved this is by creating a new node-pool, you can adjust the boot disk type and size while the creation and then moving your workloads to the new node-pool.